# Can you pass variable information through different frames

Tags: java, swing

I have a project for school where I'm building a java swing gun program for a dice game where its required to have at least two frames, on the first Frame I have the user input the amount of rounds they want to play, is it possible to keep the variable Rounds that I have assigned their input to the next frame where the actual game will be taken place?

ex. If the user inputs 3 rounds I want the next frame to know to run a loop for three rounds.

Here's my code so far I want to take the variable input for the amount if rounds to the next jframe to run a loop that runs the game the amount of rounds they entered. the next jframe is called GamePage:

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/GUIForms/JFrame.java to edit this template
 */

/**
 *
 * @author mithilansriharan
 */


public class JFrameDiceGambalingGame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form JFrameDiceGambalingGame
     */
    public JFrameDiceGambalingGame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        Background = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        lblTitle = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblRounds = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtRoundInput = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        lblRulesTitle = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblRulesL1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblRulesL2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblRulesL3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btnCont = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnExit = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Background.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));

        lblTitle.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
        lblTitle.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Helvetica Neue", 1, 48)); // NOI18N
        lblTitle.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 102));
        lblTitle.setText("Dice Game");

        lblRounds.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
        lblRounds.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Helvetica Neue", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        lblRounds.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 102));
        lblRounds.setText("How Many Rounds Would You Like To Play?:");

        txtRoundInput.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
        txtRoundInput.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
        txtRoundInput.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED, new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102), new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102), new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51), new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102)));
        txtRoundInput.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtRoundInputActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        lblRulesTitle.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
        lblRulesTitle.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Helvetica Neue", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        lblRulesTitle.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 102));
        lblRulesTitle.setText("RULES:");

        lblRulesL1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
        lblRulesL1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Helvetica Neue", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        lblRulesL1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 102));
        lblRulesL1.setText("Welcome to the Dice Game. In this game you will be against the computer");

        lblRulesL2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
        lblRulesL2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Helvetica Neue", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        lblRulesL2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 102));
        lblRulesL2.setText("Each round you and the computer will pick a number then a dice will randomly");

        lblRulesL3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
        lblRulesL3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Helvetica Neue", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        lblRulesL3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 102));
        lblRulesL3.setText("land on a number whoever picked the closest wins that round.");

        btnCont.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
        btnCont.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        btnCont.setText("Continue");
        btnCont.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
        btnCont.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnContActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnExit.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 102));
        btnExit.setText("Exit");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout BackgroundLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(Background);
        Background.setLayout(BackgroundLayout);
        BackgroundLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            BackgroundLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(btnExit, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 54, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 163, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(lblTitle)
                        .addGap(340, 340, 340))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(txtRoundInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 335, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(297, 297, 297))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(lblRounds)
                        .addGap(313, 313, 313))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(lblRulesL1)
                                .addGap(8, 8, 8))
                            .addComponent(lblRulesL2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(lblRulesL3)
                                .addGap(57, 57, 57))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(lblRulesTitle)
                                .addGap(221, 221, 221))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(btnCont, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(211, 211, 211)))
                        .addGap(201, 201, 201))))
        );
        BackgroundLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            BackgroundLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(46, 46, 46)
                .addComponent(lblTitle)
                .addGap(54, 54, 54)
                .addComponent(lblRounds)
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addComponent(txtRoundInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(btnCont, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(lblRulesTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(lblRulesL1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(lblRulesL2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(lblRulesL3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(38, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnExit)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(Background, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(Background, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void txtRoundInputActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                             

    private void btnContActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // Get input from user for the amount of rounds and convert to double
        String RoundsText = txtRoundInput.getText();
        double Rounds = Double.parseDouble(RoundsText);
                
        
        GamePage menu = new GamePage();
        menu.setVisible(true);  
        menu.run();
        
    }                                       

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameDiceGambalingGame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameDiceGambalingGame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameDiceGambalingGame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameDiceGambalingGame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JFrameDiceGambalingGame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel Background;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnCont;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnExit;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblRounds;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblRulesL1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblRulesL2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblRulesL3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblRulesTitle;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblTitle;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtRoundInput;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: An application should only have a single JFrame. If you need child windows you should use a `JDialog`. *the user input the amount of rounds they want to play,* - the easiest way to do this is to use a `JOptionPane`, (which is a custom JDialog) to prompt the user for input. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: After reading on other posts swell it seems like multiple jframes isn't the move but my teacher asked us the have at least 2 frames, is it possible to carry the variable I set it the first frame to the next frame with he infromation it holds

Comment: Yes, it's possible to share state between windows. It's fundamentally no different from sharing state between any two objects.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no problem to write an application with multiple frames.
Here is an example with two frames that are open in parallel. Data entered into either one will be visible in the other one.

The secret is that both JTextFields share the same document (or in Slaw's words: The text fields share state).

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TwoFrames {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTextField t1 = new JTextField();
        t1.setColumns(30);
        JTextField t2 = new JTextField();
        t2.setColumns(30);
        
        // make the two fields share the same content
        t2.setDocument(t1.getDocument());
        
        JFrame f1 = new JFrame("Frame 1");
        f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f1.add(t1);
        f1.pack();
        f1.setVisible(true);

        JFrame f2 = new JFrame("Frame 2");
        f2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f2.add(t2);
        f2.pack();
        f2.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And just to demonstrate this 'sharing state' does not depend on the amount of frames, here is a similar example with only one frame. Spot the difference.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class OneFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTextField t1 = new JTextField();
        t1.setColumns(30);
        JTextField t2 = new JTextField();
        t2.setColumns(30);
        
        // make the two fields share the same content
        t2.setDocument(t1.getDocument());
        
        JFrame f1 = new JFrame("Frame");
        f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f1.add(t1);
        f1.add(t2);
        f1.pack();
        f1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```